# Android: How can I resume an app from background from service without calling onCreate method?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

When you leave an app by pressing home button or something else, overlay window has been shown. I would like to implement action when this window is touched, the app will be resume with current activity and data. I know how to resume the app with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in intent, it works, but it is not what i want. I would like to keep data of this activity when resume has begin.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're dealing with problem which does not exist. Android resumes Activities in the state it was before going to background. See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states. Please be more specific - what exactly does not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

To resume the task in the same state as it was when the user left it, you just do exactly what Android does when it wants to resume the app:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

This will bring the existing task back to the foreground in whatever state it was when it went to the background.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is keeping the data a live, you should look into `ViewModel`. It's a concept from google itself where you can store your UI data.

E.g. you fetch a list of users and store it in a ViewModel. If the corresponding View is recreated, the instance of the ViewModel is kept in memory and you can simple obtain it from that object.

More info: [ViewModel Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: My activity rendering a map with current position, the navigation, and when i resume it manually navigation keep going, and I need apply this approach programmatically.